# Return only last 80 days of my dataframe

Tags: r, timestamp, subset

I have a data frame of around 500,000 rows which goes back just over a year. I have a column of timestamps (1525078225,1525078806, etc..). I'm only interested in looking at the last 80 days of my data (the last time stamp of my data isn't necessarily the current day). What would be the easiest way of doing this?
I have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to subset it properly. Any help would be much appreciated here. Thanks

```
diff = as.numeric(max(df$Timestamp, na.rm = TRUE) - (80*24*60*60))
df[df$Timestamp <= diff,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to use something like this:

`diff = as.numeric(Sys.time() - 80*24*60*60)`

as.numeric(Sys.time()) will return the current time in seconds from 1970
so we just subtract 80 days time in seconds

`df[df$timestamp >= diff]`

this will filter the rows by column and after that you can manipulate the formats of that data as you wish

Answer (score 0):

An easy way that comes to mind is to go to https://www.epochconverter.com/, and convert 80 days ago to Epoch Unix. 80 days before today was April 22, 2018; the timestamp for 04/22/2018 at 12:00:00 AM is 1524355200. Now that you have this timestamp, use `sqldf` to filter your data. For example:

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
result = sqldf("SELECT * FROM df WHERE timestamp >= 1524355200")
```

The `result` dataframe would be the last 80 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tail(YourDataFrame, 80)
```

Comment: This works only if there's exactly one row per day.  If I'm understand the OP correctly, there are multiple rows per day (ie, 500k rows were generated in about 365 days).